# How to create an attached property for the loaded event to focus on an element in VB.Net and WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I want to be able to add a line to my User Control that will focus on a certain element during the loaded event for the User Control:

```
<UserControl custom:FocusOnElement.FocusOn="{Binding ElementName=MyTextBox}">
<TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" Text="Focus on me" />
```

My custom attached property class looks like this:

```
Public NotInheritable Class FocusOnElement

Public Shared FocusOnProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("FocusOn", GetType(FrameworkElement), GetType(FocusOnElement), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(AddressOf OnSetCallback))

Private Sub New()
End Sub

Public Shared Function GetFocusOn(element As UIElement) As FrameworkElement
    Return CType(element.GetValue(FocusOnProperty), FrameworkElement)
End Function

Public Shared Sub SetFocusOn(element As UIElement, value As FrameworkElement)
    element.SetValue(FocusOnProperty, value)
End Sub

Public Shared Sub FocusOnTarget(target As FrameworkElement)
    Input.Keyboard.Focus(target)
End Sub

Public Shared Sub OnSetCallback(dependencyObject As DependencyObject, dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    Dim fwElement As FrameworkElement = TryCast(dependencyObject, FrameworkElement)
    If fwElement Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Dim target = GetFocusOn(fwElement)
    If target Is Nothing Then Return

    AddHandler fwElement.Loaded, Sub() FocusOnTarget(target)
End Sub
End Class
```

When I run the code, MyTextBox doesn't receive focus but I don't get any errors. What could I be doing wrong? Any help or pointers or things to try out would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Figured it out with this binding in the XAML: `<UserControl custom:FocusOnElement.FocusOn="{x:Reference MyTextBox}">`